# Smallest value of n

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=1/3$. determine the smallest integer n can be such that $P(X\ge1)\ge0.85$. In this problem  I am stuck with $\frac{2^n (2^{-1}n+1)}{3^n}\ge0.15$

Comment: Your expression looks like the solution to $P(X\gt1)\le 0.85$ rather than $P(X\ge1)\ge 0.85$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Pr(X \ge 1)=1-\Pr(X=0)=1-\left(\frac23\right)^n$.

If this is greater than or equal to $0.85$ then  $\left(\frac23\right)^n \le 0.15$, i.e. $n \log(2/3) \le \log(0.15)$.

Note the negative logarithms and you get $n \ge \dfrac{\log(20)-\log(3)}{\log(3)-\log(2)}$.

Calculate and round up to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

$P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X=0)$
$P(X=0)$ should be simpler than your expression.